# What is the length and characters in ids generated by elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation) of elastic search states:

> The index operation can be executed without specifying the id. In such
>   a case, an id will be generated automatically.

But it does not provide any information about the properties of the ids.

- What is the length (minimun/maximum)? 

  my guess is `22`.
- Which characters are used in the id? 

   My guess is `[-_A-Za-z0-9]`
- Can the properties of the generated ids change at any time (is that part of the API)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auto-generated ids are random [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded [UUIDs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). The base64 algorithm is used in [URL-safe mode](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html) hence `-` and `_` characters might be present in ids.

Comment: Yes - base64 UUID works out to 22 bytes.  Well under the MS Sql Server 900 byte max index size for anyone interested or using mssql with references to elasticsearch docs

Answer (score 5):

Auto-generated ids by elasticsearch are exactly 20 characters length (not 22 characters) and encoded by url-safe base64 algorithm [-_A-Za-z0-9].

Read more in documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index-doc.html#_autogenerating_ids